# Inserting a child entity with parent in Symfony

Tags: php, orm, symfony

I have a parent entity which is referring to a child entity and the classes are written as follows:

```
class MyEntity {
  /**
  * ORM Annotations
  */
  private $id;

  /**
  * ORM Annotations
  */
  private $name;

  /**
  * @var string
  * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Picture")
  */
  private $image;

  /** Getters & Setters **/
}

private Image {
  private $id;
  private $image_url;
}
```

Here, Image is a weak entity and I don't want to insert image before inserting `MyEntity` object. Basically, my question is, how can I render the form for `MyEntity` so that, `Image` form appears as a part of it, and image get saved when I save `MyEntity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How come your code has `targetEntity="Picture"` and you have defined `Image` as child Entity. I guess there is a typo, you need to correct.

You need to add `cascade={"persist", "update"}` to your `image` association in `MyEntity`.

This will make sure, Image entity being created / updated along with `MyEntity`.

**Now the form Part**

Create a new `FormType` for `Image`, lets call it as `ImageType`.
In your `MyEntity` FormType, add the new FormType as a new field :

```
$builder
    ->add('image', ImageType::class, array(
        'label' => 'Image'
));
```

Now on form Submission, The child entity (Image) will be created / updated accordingly.

**Note** : You need to take care of image upload explicitly.

Hope this helps!